# How to upload Large Datasets in BigQuery (Free Version)?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I am working on [Cyclistic Marketing Case Study](https://www.theaccountingtactics.com/2023/06/cyclistic-marketing-case-study-2023.html) - Google Capstone Project, a part of Google Data Analytics Program. I used Excel to process but I want to like to manipulate in Big Query.

When I uploaded it to Big Query using Excel (CSV files 100,000+rows), it did not push because it has a limit of 16,000 rows.

Is there another way to upload CSV files to BigQuery? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the CSV file in a GCS bucket and then upload it to BigQuery by following this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv).

You can follow below steps for loading the csv file into BQ

Step 1.  In the Google Cloud console, go to the BigQuery page. In the Explorer pane, expand your project, and then create a dataset.

Step2. In the Dataset info section, click 3 dots then Create table. In the Create table panel,  specify the following details:

- In the Source section, select Google Cloud Storage in the Create table from the list. Then, do the following :

1. Select file from the cloud storage bucket, or enter the cloud storage URI. You cannot include multiple URIs in the Google Cloud console, but wildcards are supported. The Cloud storage bucket must be in the same location as the dataset that contains the table you want to create, append, or overwrite.
2. For File format, select CSV.

- Setup the  the Destination section and schema section as per your requirement.

Step3. Click the Create table.